# How to get a range of Date in a column in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

| Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-02-14 | 2020-02-18 |

so the output column  looks like

| Start Date | End Date | Date_range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-14 | 2020-02-18 | [2020-02-14,2020-02-15,2020-02-16,2020-02-17,2020-02-18] |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.date_range`:

```
date_range = lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start Date'], x['End Date']).date.tolist()
df['Date_range'] = df.apply(date_range, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
   Start Date    End Date                                                    Date_range
0  2020-02-14  2020-02-18  [2020-02-14, 2020-02-15, 2020-02-16, 2020-02-17, 2020-02-18]
```